# How can I call a lambda without defining it as a function?

Tags: python, lambda

For lambda functions in the following code,

```
def myfunc(n):
  return lambda a : a * n
mydoubler = myfunc(2)
print(mydoubler(11))
```

I am trying to understand why `mydoubler` becomes `<class 'function'>` and how I can call `mydoubler(11)` without defining it as a function.

Comment: A `lambda` _is_ a function. The concept to research is: higher-order functions.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "lambda function". A lambda *expression* is an expression that creates `function` objects, the same as a `def` statement.

Comment: @jonsharpe :I am still confused .for a normal function if i write x = normal_fun(x) ,x will be a variable .For lambda how does the return function make it a function..I will go through "higher order function " and try to understand the same once again

Comment: @Pythontrack Your `myfunc` is also a normal function, it is just returning a lambda. If you try this `mydoubler = myfunc(2)(11) ` your `mydoubler` will become 22, but after this you can't use `mydoubler` as a function.

Answer (score 2):

A `lambda` is a function, but with only one expression (line of code).
That expression is executed when the function is called, and the result is returned.

So the equivalent of this lambda:

```py
double = lambda x: x * 2
```

is this `def` function:

```py
def double(x):
    return x * 2
```

You can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp)

Answer (score 0):

A lambda is a function, so your code is doing something like

```
def myfunc(n):
    def result(a):
        return a * n
    return result # returns a function

mydoubler = myfunc(2)
print(f(11))
```

You're asking how to call `mydoubler` without defining it as a function, which isn't the clearest question, but you can call it without naming it like so

```
print( myfunc(2)(11) )
```

Comment: my question was why mydoubler executes the lambda expression as its not defined as a function.Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @Pythontrack but it is a function, what do you expect it to be?

Comment: didnt know that mydoubler becomes a function in line3.I was assuming it will be a variable.Just starting out new to programming.

Comment: @Pythontrack it is a variable, which is referencing a function object. What do you think the value of `mydoubler` should be? An int? What specific value would you expect it to be in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Your `myfunc` is returning a lambda. Lambda is a small anonymous function. A lambda can take any number of arguments, but can only have one expression.

So after execution of the 3rd line, your `mydoubler` will become a lambda that's why when you try `print(type(mydoubler))` it will return `<class 'function'>`.

Also in order to call `mydoubler` with 11, it must be function.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.I understand i misquoted my question here." My question actually was "why " does mydoubler(11) work as a function wiht argument (11) and execute the expression defined in lambda ,even though I havent defined "mydoubler()":.I guess its because as classhacker explained "mydoubler will become a lambda" and executes the expression in my_func().Hope my understanding is right

Answer (score 0):

A lambda expression, like a `def` statement, defines functions. Your code could be equivalently written as

```
def myfunc(n):
  def _(a):
    return a * n
  return _
mydoubler = myfunc(2)
print(mydoubler(11))
```

Because the inner function is simple enough to be defined as a single expression, using a lambda expression saves you the trouble of coming up with the otherwise unused name the `def` statement requires.

The key here is that the inner function *closes* over the value of `n`, so that the function returned by `myfunc` retains a reference to the value of the argument passed to `myfunc`. That is, `mydoubler` is hard-coded to multiply *its* argument by 2, rather than whatever value `n` may get later. (Indeed, the purpose of the closure is to create a *new* variable `n` used by the inner function, one which cannot easily be changed from outside `myfunc`.)

Answer (score 0):

using decorator you can achive this

```
from functools import wraps

def decorator_func_with_args(arg1):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(val):
            result = f(val)
            return result(arg1)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
    
@decorator_func_with_args(arg1=2)
def myfunc(n):
    return lambda arg:arg*n
    

result = myfunc(1211)
print(result)
```

output

`2422`

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean this?

```
mydoubler = lambda a : a * 2
mydoubler(11)
```